# How to add UserManagerExtension class methods in Asp.Net Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am migrating my current project to core, and in my current project I have many synchronous method calls from [UserManagerExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.usermanagerextensions(v=vs.108).aspx) class like `Create`, `FindById`, `AddToRole` etc. But despite thorough searching online I am not able to find the same in core.

Is it deprecated in core 2.0? If not, what is the namespace and how to include it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, they are gone. However, their existence was suspect even before. All the extensions did was simply run the async versions "synchronously", which basically means they spun off a task that blocked on the async call until it completed. While this technically satisfies having a "synchronous" method, it's actually really bad for web applications as you're sacrificing threads from your pool to do the work synchronously.

In ASP.NET MVC, it was a necessary evil, though, since there were many aspects that did not support async: child actions, action filters, etc. However, in Core, everything is async, and things happening in a web application space should be async. Therefore, there's simply no good reason to ever use sync methods, so that's probably why they no longer exist.

If you still need to run the async methods as sync, for some reason, you can simply block on them yourself:

```
var user = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Be aware, though, that can deadlock in certain situations, because of the context shift. The two ways to avoid that are:

1. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)`

   ```
   var user = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   ```

   However, you cannot use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in something like an action method, since the context must be maintained in order to complete the response. You can use it in a method called by the action method, though:

   ```
   private ApplicationUser GetUser(string id)
   {
       return UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   }

   ...

   var user = GetUser(id);
   ```
2. Run it in a different thread

   ```
   Task.Run(() => {
       var user = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
       // code here that needs `user`
   });
   ```

   As you can see, with this method the work you send off must be self-contained, so it's probably not a good fit in most scenarios. Also, again, this is extremely bad for web applications.

Long and short, there's not really a good way to run async as sync, and you should avoid it as much as possible. Async should be async all the way. That did use to be an issue in MVC, but now it's not with Core.

Comment: I'd guessed they must have been killed. But it vanished so silently without any clear documentation make it a conspiracy :P Thanks a lot for confirming and for such a great answer